# lapply returns series of vectors and not a single one

Tags: r

I have a function that I wrote that transforms a character input to a numeric output.

```
votedIndicated <- function(votedCode) {
  switch(votedCode,
         "V" = 1,
         "A" = 1,
         "M" = 1,
         "O" = 1,
         "T" = 1,
         "P" = 1,
         "L" = 1,
         "D" = 0)
}
```

When I run it, I get the expected return:

```
> votedIndicated("V")
[1] 1
> votedIndicated("D")
[1] 0
```

However, when I try and apply this function to a vector, I am not getting back another vector but a series of single valued vectors (I think I said that right)

```
> foo <- c("V","V","D")
> bar <- lapply(foo, votedIndicated)
> bar
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 0
```

How can I make bar like this `bar <- c(1,1,0)`?

Comment: `Vectorize(votedIndicated)(c("V","V","D"))`

Comment: You could do this without a function at all. Just make a lookup vector. `vcode <- c("V"=1,"A"=1,"M"=1,"O"=1,"T"=1,"P"= 1,"L"= 1,"D"=0); vcode[foo]`

Comment: `sapply(foo, votedIndicated)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "series of single valued vectors" you refer to is called a **list** in R.  A list is a vector as well, but you are looking to return an **atomic** vector.  For that, and since you know that the return value will always be a single numeric value, you can use `vapply()`.

```
vapply(foo, votedIndicated, 1)
# V V D 
# 1 1 0
```

Or if you don't want the names,

```
vapply(foo, votedIndicated, 1, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] 1 1 0
```

For more about `vapply()`, see `help(vapply)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep what you have got already.

```
as.vector(do.call(rbind,bar))
```

gives:

```
[1] 1 1 0
```

Comment: `unlist(bar)` seems easier